# Salesforce Scheduled Flow Filter Conditions for RecordTypeId

Tags: scheduled-flow

Looking for Suggestions on Salesforce scheduled flow. I want this flow to run everyday around midnight. One of the criteria I have is the `RecordTypeId`. Since this is a newly created Record Type, it's `Id` will be different in all environments. Couple of ideas that I have are creating a `$Label` but it's value will be different too (but a centralized place) or I can create a private variable in the Flow to save this value but it will still need a org specific change after the deployment. I can't add `RecordType.DeveloperName` to the filter Condition of the flow (I get a validation error).
One more idea is I can create a formula field for the record type developer name but it will eat into my indexed fields as the `RecordTypeId` provides me out of the box index field.

Comment: funny you should ask this as this request is enumerated in the current January 2024  https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/prioritization.  If you have other indexed fields like createdDate, I wouldn't worry about the formula field

Comment: Awesome @cropredy
Thank you so much